# find the first duplicate element in an array having the minimal index

Tags: java, arrays, hashset

I have an array containing some duplicate elements like this :

find the first duplicate number for which the second occurrence has the minimal index. In other words, if there are more than 1 duplicated numbers, return the number for which the second occurrence has a smaller index than the second occurrence of the other number does. If there are no such elements, return -1

For a = [2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 2], the output should be
firstDuplicate(a) = 3.

There are 2 duplicates: numbers 2 and 3. The second occurrence of 3 has a smaller index than the second occurrence of 2 does, so the answer is 3.

I tried this :

```
int firstDuplicate(int[] a) {
  Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
  Map<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
  Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> min = null;
  for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
       // if(!hm.containsKey(a[i]))
              hm.put(a[i],i);
  }
  for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : hm.entrySet()){
        if(min == null || entry.getValue() < min.getValue()){
              min = entry;
        }
  }
  return min == null ? new Integer(-1) : min.getKey();
```

}

It's not working out, but I got another solution online which is like this :

```
int firstDuplicate(int[] a) {
  Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
  Map<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
  Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> min = null;
  for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        if(set.add(a[i])==false && !hm.containsKey(a[i]))
              hm.put(a[i],i);
  }
  for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : hm.entrySet()){
        if(min == null || entry.getValue() < min.getValue()){
              min = entry;
        }
  }
  return min == null ? new Integer(-1) : min.getKey();
```

}

Can anyone please explain me the use of Hashset here, as it doesn't allow the duplicates so how that if condition will be workable.

Comment: It basically computes a hashmap whose key the element and the value the index of its duplicate. It then computes search for the min index in the hashmap.

Comment: `Set.add` will return `false` if the set already contains the object you want to add. So by checking if the return value is `false` you can check if the object was already in the set. If it was not in the set yet (and is the second occurence, not a later one) you save it's position in a map. This results in a map with all duplicates and their first occurence. Nwo you simply see which one was the first double and you are done. You could greatly shorten this code with some stream logic though to be honest or by just returning on the first false as this is obviously the earliest duplicate...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason your first attempt failed is that you add the array elements as keys to the `Map` without checking if they are already there, which means you can't know if there are any duplicates by the time you finish populating the `Map`.

The alternative code you found does something different. It uses the `Set` to determine if the current array element already appeared earlier in the array, and if that's the case, it adds it as key to the `Map` only if it's not already there. This means that the `Map` will only contain elements that appear multiple times in the array, and the index associated with each element is the occurrence of the first duplicate. I.e. for the array `{2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 2}`, the `Map` will contain `{2=5, 3=4}`. Then it will return the key having the smallest value (which corresponds with the index of the first duplicate).

However, the `Map` is unnecessary, since you only need to find one duplicate, not all of them. Use the `Set` to locate the first duplicate and return it:

```
int firstDuplicate(int[] a) 
{
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        if(!set.add(a[i])) {
            return a[i];
        }
    }
    return -1; // no duplicates found 
}
```

This relies on `set.add()` returning `false` if the `Set` already contains the element you wish to add. Once it returns `false` for the first time, you found the first duplicate.

Comment: This code does not return the first duplicate having minimal index. It returns the first duplicate. For the example asked in the question it returns 2 and not 3

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO No, it will return 3, since the second 3 of the array will be encountered before the second 2.

Answer (score 6):

I would strongly recommend you to try this to get the correct results

you can make it more efficient time complexity O(n)

```
int firstDuplicate(int[] a){
int n = a.length;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
   if(a[Math.abs(a[i])-1]<0) return Math.abs(a[i]);
   else a[Math.abs(a[i])-1] = - a[Math.abs(a[i])-1];
}
return -1;
}
```

Comment: Nice one, it has O(n) time and O(1) space complexity, so more efficient than the accepted answer.

Comment: This is not a general solution. It's only valid if all elements in `a` are greater than 1 and are at most `a.length`.

Comment: Could someone please explain the idea behind this solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
int firstDuplicate(int[] a){
int n = a.length;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
    if(a[Math.abs(a[i])-1]<0) return Math.abs(a[i]);
    else a[Math.abs(a[i])-1] = - a[Math.abs(a[i])-1];
   }
return -1;
}
```

I will explain why and how this one works.
It's important that this constrain: `1 ≤ a[i] ≤ a.length` is present, meaning that in an array like this: `a = [2,8,2]` this algorithm **WILL NOT work** because **8** is **bigger** than `a.length` in this case **3**.

You'll find the explanation [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-frequencies-elements-array-o1-extra-space-time/) as well:

### Hashmap

This solution follows the idea of a hashmap. Another structure where you count `hash[arr[i]-1]++` the number of occurrences for any given index `i` in the array. Example:

If you have `arr[2,1,3,5,3,2]` hashmap will begin in an 6 zero array: `hashmap[0,0,0,0,0,0]` because that's the size of `arr`. As the algorithm progress it will sum `+1` in the position `arr[i]-1`. It's using the value as the index of the sum. At then end you get: `arr[1,2,2,0,1,0]`.

This has ***O(n)*** in time complexity because it runs the full arr, and ***O(n)*** in time because it runs the array at least 1 time.

### Without Hashmap

The idea of the algorithm above is that you don't need the extra structure of a hashmap but can use the same array to count the frequency. This might lead to a problem. Let `i-th` element be `a` or (`arr[i]=a`) then the count should be stored at `arr[arr[i]-1]` or (`arr[a-1]`), but when the frequency will be stored the element will be lost.

Example iteration:

1. `a[2,1,3,5,3,2]` -> `a[2,1,3,5,3,2]`
2. `a[2,1,3,5,3,2]` -> `a[1,1,3,5,3,2]`
3. `a[1,1,3,5,3,2]` -> `a[1,1,1,5,3,2]`
4. `a[1,1,1,5,3,2]` -> `a[1,1,1,5`**`,1`**,`2]` As you can see we lost the value of `3` when we read `5` as it stored the frequency in `arr[arr[4]-1]` or (`arr[5-1]`).

##### Solve the missing problem

To solve this problem first we put replace the i-th element with `arr[arr[i]-1]` or (`arr[a-1]`) then put `-1` at array `arr[arr[i]-1]` or (`arr[a-1]`).
The algorithm:

1. Traverse the array from start to end.
2. For each element check if the element is less than or equal to zero or not. If negative or zero skip the element as it is frequency.
3. If an element (`a = arr[i] – 1`) is positive, then check if `arr[a]` is positive or not. If positive then that means it is the first occurrence of `a` in the array and replace `arr[i]` with `arr[a]`, and assign `arr[a] = -1`. If `arr[a]` is negative, then it is not the first occurrence, then update `arr[a]` as `arr[a]--` and update `arr[i]` as `arr[i] = 0`. You use an auxiliary value to save arr[a] that will be used in the next iteration.
4. Again, traverse the array and print `i+1` as value and `arr[i]` as frequency.

Example iteration:

1. `a[2,1,3,5,3,2]` -> `a[1,1,3,5,3,2]` -> `a[1,-1,3,5,3,2]`
2. `a[1,-1,3,5,3,2]` -> `a[1,-1,3,5,3,2]` -> `a[1,-1,-1,5,3,2]`
3. `a[1,-1,-1,5,3,2]` -> `a[1,-1,-1,0,3,2]`
4. `a[1,-1,-1,0,3,2]` -> `a[1,-1,-1,0,-1,2]` -> `a[1,-1,-2,0,-1,2]`
5. `a[1,-1,-2,0,-1,2]` -> `a[1,-1,-2,0,-1,0]`
6. `a[1,-1,-2,0,-1,0]` -> `a[1,-2,-2,0,-1,0]`

### firstDuplicate

After knowing this we can now grasp how `firstDuplicate` works. The idea is not to count the frequency but instead just print the `index` that has already a negative in frequency. When we get a negative frequency we return.
So running the algorithm we get:

1. With `if(a[2-1]<0)` or `if(1<0)` this comparation is between `arr[arr[0]-1]` or (`arr[1]`) and `0` so we don't return. `a[2,1,3,5,3,2]` -> `a[2,-1,3,5,3,2]`
2. With `if(a[1-1]<0)` or `if(2<0)` we don't return `a[2,-1,3,5,3,2]` -> `a[-1,-1,3,5,3,2]`.
3. With `if(a[3-1]<0)` or `if(3<0)` we don't return. `a[-1,-1,3,5,3,2]` -> `a[-2,-1,-3,5,3,2]`
4. With `if(a[5-1]<0)` or `if(3<0)` we don't return. `a[-2,-1,-3,5,3,2]` -> `a[-2,-1,-3,5,-3,2]`
5. With `if(a[3-1]<0)` or `if(-3<0)` we return.

**All of this is based on the idea that `element-1` is the index.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use java 8 with lambda and stream.

Here is the code in one line :

```
Set<Integer> allItems = new HashSet<>();
Arrays.stream(a).filter(i -> !allItems.add(i)).findFirst().orElse(-1)
```

it returns what you expect

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to implement this problem, by using a HashSet with time complexity o(n) and by using nested loops o(n2)

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    for(int j = i +1; j < a.length; j++){
           if(a[i] == a[j]){
                   System.out.println(a[i]);
                   return;
           }
     }
 }
```

Or you can make it more efficient time complexity O(n)

```
int index -1;
Set<Integer> hashSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
for(int i = a.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
     if(hashSet.contains(a[i])){
           index = i;
     }else{
           hashSet.add(a[i]);
     }
}
 System.out.println(a[index]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int firstDuplicate(int[] a)
    {
        int DupIndex = 0;
        int DupValue = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < a.Length; j++)
            {
                if (a[i] == a[j])
               {
                    if (j < DupIndex)
                    {
                        DupIndex = j;
                        DupValue = a[i];
                    }
                    else if (DupIndex == 0)
                    {
                        DupIndex = j;
                        DupValue = a[i];
                    }
                }
            };
        };
        return (DupValue == 0) ? -1 : DupValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int array[]={2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 2};
    int tempArray[]=new int[array.length];
    int index=0;
    while(index< array.length){
        if(++(tempArray[array[index]])==2) 
            break;
        index++;
    }
    if(index> array.length){
        System.out.println("No Duplicate");
    }else {
        System.out.println("First Duplicate " + array[index]);
    }
}
```

Use counting sort, sweet and simple :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Java implementation 
Time complexity O(n) -- Linear
Space Complexity O(n) -- Linear

//Approach
//run a loop and try to insert it into a map.
//check if map contains key for arr[nextValue]
//if contains key, break loop and return value.
//if not, keep on adding in the map.

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ReturnFirstRecurringCharacter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr1 = {2,5,5,2};
        Integer recurringNumber = checkForRecurringNumber(arr1);
        if (recurringNumber != null) {
            System.out.println(recurringNumber);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Undefined");
        }
    }

    private static Integer checkForRecurringNumber(int[] arr1) {
        try {
            if (arr1 != null) {
                Map<Integer, Integer> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
                    if (dataMap.containsKey(arr1[i])) {
                        return arr1[i];
                    }
                    dataMap.put(arr1[i], i);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

JS solution:

function solution(a) {

```
const map = {};

for(let i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    if(map[a[i]]) {
        if(map[a[i]][0] === 1) {
        map[a[i]][0]++ ;
        map[a[i]][1] = i;
        }
    } else {
        map[a[i]] = [1, i];
    }
}



const data = Object.keys(map).filter(key => map[key][0] == 2).map(el => parseInt(el));


let smallest = Infinity;
let smallestData = -1;
for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if(map[data[i]][1] < smallest) {
        smallest = map[data[i]][1];
        smallestData = data[i];
    }
}
    
return smallestData;
```

}

Answer (score -2):

**Solution in Javascript**

```js
function solution(a) {
    let i = -1;
    while (++i < a.length)
        if (a.indexOf(a[i]) !== i)
            return a[i];

    return -1;
}

console.log(solution([2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 2])); // 3
console.log(solution([2, 2])); // 2
console.log(solution([2, 4, 3, 5, 1])); // -1
```

Comment: The question is tagged as [java].